# MVC Filter attribute - multiple options as filter parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

Hi I have a custom filter attribute for my `C#` Controllers.

```
 [SessionExpireFilterAttribute(UserType = UserTypes.Admin)]
```

My Filter starts like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class SessionExpireFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public App.Model.UserTypes UserType { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
```

What I would like is to be able to send multiple `UserTypes` so the permission to this controller is not just associated to one.

For example want to set something like this:

```
[SessionExpireFilterAttribute(UserType = UserTypes.Admin || UserTypes.Accounting || UserTypes.Standard)]
```

That way if the user type is `Admin` or `Accounting` or `Standard` I can do my logic in my filter and let the process continue.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array for that, something like this:

```
public App.Model.UserTypes[] UserTypes { get; set; }

public SessionExpireFilterAttribute(params App.Model.UserType[] values) {
    UserTypes = values;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
[SessionExpireFilterAttribute(UserTypes.Admin, UserTypes.Accounting, UserTypes.Standard)]
```

Note: You don't have to use `params`, you can also just do

```
[SessionExpireFilterAttribute(new [] {UserTypes.Admin, UserTypes.Accounting, UserTypes.Standard})]
```

Comment: Thanks Appreciate it